# Split and distribute line in perl

Tags: perl

I have this form of line:

```
xxx| aaa yyy| bbb ccc zzz| ddd eee
```

I want to split and distribute in this array with perl:

```
xxx| aaa
yyy| bbb
yyy| ccc
zzz| ddd
zzz| eee
```

Comment: Please provide a better description of what you want to achieve. It is not obvious what you want given your sample input and output.

Comment: Why is `yyy| ccc` in there while `xxx| bbb` and `zzz| eee` are not?

Comment: Anyway oneliner `perl -lne'for(split/ (?=\w+\|)/){($p,@a)=split/ /;print"$p $_"for@a}'`

Comment: Why was this question closed? It's clear what the OP wants to do.

Comment: `perl -wE '$_="xxx| aaa yyy| bbb ccc zzz| ddd eee"; my %a; while (s/(\w+)\|([ \w]+\b(?!\|))//) { $a{$1} = [ split ' ',$2 ] }; for my $key (keys %a) { for my $val (@{$a{$key}}) { say qq($key | $val); } }"`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: If you have an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: @TLP: If that's an answer (which, though I haven't test it, it appears to be), please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, transferred from comments. I put it there while the question was closed.

With a substitution regex, we iterate through the string, extracting a key and the values. The value string is split on whitespace, and stored in an anonymous array in `%hash`, with the corresponding key.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10; # to enable say

$_="xxx| aaa yyy| bbb ccc zzz| ddd eee"; 
my %hash; 
while (s/(\w+)\|([ \w]+\b(?!\|))//) { 
    $hash{$1} = [ split ' ',$2 ];
}
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    for my $val (@{$hash{$key}}) { 
        say "$key | $val";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
xxx | aaa
yyy | bbb
yyy | ccc
zzz | ddd
zzz | eee
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner solution:

```
perl -lne'for(split/ (?=\w+\|)/){($p,@a)=split/ /;print"$p $_"for@a}'
```

usage:

```
$ echo "xxx| aaa yyy| bbb ccc zzz| ddd eee" | perl -lne'for(split/ (?=\w+\|)/){($p,@a)=split/ /;print"$p $_"for@a}'
xxx| aaa
yyy| bbb
yyy| ccc
zzz| ddd
zzz| eee
```